# Remove borders and gridlines around google chart timeline

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, timeline

I need to remove the border and the gridlines from the google charts timetable (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline))

Right now it looks like this: [with borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZirSm.png)
It should look like this: [without borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiU9a.png)

I made a stackblitz for it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ozv5hr?file=index.html

It seems like the config options that you can use for example with line charts do not work with timelines.

Comment: This might be the right question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19298332/533976

Comment: this question pertains to the timeline chart, which has different options than that of charts found in the corechart package, such as the combo chart used in the answer found by @vovchisko. the solution will not work here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no config options available for removing the borders,
but we can remove them manually on the chart's `'ready'` event.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", {
  packages: ["timeline"]
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById("timeline");
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: "string", id: "Label" });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: "string", id: "Type" });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: "date", id: "Start" });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: "date", id: "End" });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ["A", "A", new Date(2021, 0, 0, 0), new Date(2021, 0, 0, 1)],
    ["A", "B", new Date(2021, 0, 0, 1), new Date(2021, 0, 0, 2)],
    ["A", "C", new Date(2021, 0, 0, 2), new Date(2021, 0, 0, 3)]
  ]);

  var options = {
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true,
      showRowLabels: false,
      showBarLabels: false
    },
    avoidOverlappingGridLines: false,
    hAxis: {
      format: "HH:mm"
    },
    gridlines: {
      color: "none"
    }
  };

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // find <rect> elements
    var rects = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rects, function(rect) {
      if (rect.getAttribute('stroke') === '#9a9a9a') {
        // remove border
        rect.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
      }
    });

    // find <path> elements
    var paths = container.getElementsByTagName('path');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(paths, function(path) {
      if ((path.getAttribute('stroke') === '#ffffff') || (path.getAttribute('stroke') === '#e6e6e6')) {
        // remove border
        path.setAttribute('stroke-width', '0');
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: It does but it is one year old. I was hoping to find a new solution that is not modifying the svg manually

Comment: well then tanks ;)